# 11gR2 JDeveloper: Where is this application setting?

Tags: jdeveloper

I have been developing with 11gR1 JDeveloper (11.1.1.6) for past few months now. I am now moving to JDeveloper 11gR2 (11.1.2.2). The only problem I face right now is I can't find the "Auto Generate and Synchronize weblogic-jdbc.xml Descriptors During Deployment" checkbox in 11gR2 JDeveloper! 11gR2 JDeveloper doesnt have any of the security settings

Here's JDeveloper 11.1.1.6:

[image: Jdeveloper 11.1.1.6]

Here's JDeveloper 11.1.2.2:

[image: Jdeveloper 11.1.2.2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah... i click "WebLogic" under "Deployment", then click "Load WebLogic Extension" Button, then i can click the check box.

Leave it to Oracle to make things more complicated than what they should be. [image: oracle...]